# Finding an inflection point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone help me find an inflection point for the following function without using graphing calculator.

Determine the intervals of concavity and points of inflection for the function

$f(x)=x\sqrt{25-x^2}$

for my first derivative I did

$f'(x)=1\sqrt{25-x^2}+(x)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{25-x^2}}(-2x)$

for my common denominator I got

$\frac{50-4x^2}{2\sqrt{25-x^2}}$

for my second derivative I got

$f''(x)=\frac{(-4x)\sqrt{25-x^2}-(25-2x^2)(1/2)\sqrt{25-x^2}(-2x)}{\sqrt{(25-x^2)^2}}$

But I am having trobule finding the inflection point.

Comment: The first step to finding an inflection point is locating where the second derivative equals zero. For what values of $x$ does $f''(x)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, simplify your $f'(x)$ before taking the second derivative.

$$f'(x)= \dfrac{(\sqrt{25-x^2})^2 - (x^2)}{\sqrt{25-x^2}} $$ 
$$ = \dfrac{25 - 2x^2}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$$

Now use the quotient rule to compute $f''(x)$.

(You need to correct your $f''(x)$ and simplify, to find the common denominator), then determine when $f''(x) = 0$. That's where an inflection point would be.

Of course, we also need to check $x = 5, x = -5$ because that is where the denominator will be zero, and the derivatives (first and second) undefined. So just check what is happening there $f(0)$, however, will be zero as well.

$$f''(x) = \frac{(-4x)\sqrt{25-x^2}-(25-2x^2)\large\frac{-x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}}{25-x^2} $$ 
$$ = \frac{(-4x)(25-x^2)-(25-2x^2)(-x)}{(25-x^2)\sqrt{25-x^2}} $$ 
$$ = \frac{-75x+2x^3}{(25-x^2)^{\large\frac32}} $$ 
$$ = \frac{x(2x^2 - 75)}{(25-x^2)^{\large\frac32}} $$
$$ = \frac{2x(x^2 - \frac{75}{2})}{(25 - x^2)^{\large \frac 32}}$$

Now, when is $f''(x) = 0$? Be careful with $x = 5, x= -5$: you want to check the point, but note that neither the first nor the second derivative is defined there.

When $2x = 0,\; f''(x) = 0$, as is $f'$ and $f$. 
When $x^2 - 75/2 = 0, f''(x) = 0 \implies x \pm 5\sqrt{\frac 32} = 0 \implies $

But to confirm that that there is an ***inflection point*** at $x=0$, ***you'll want to check whether $f''(x)$ changes signs on there***, from negative to positive, or positive to negative. It does, indeed change signs at $x = 0$: as $x \to 0$ from the left, $f''(x) > 0$, and when $x \to 0$ from the right, $f''(x) <0$. So there is, indeed, an inflection point at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: So would my second derivative be correct? Then I can set it to zero to find the inflection point.

Comment: I have an idea I can find a common denominator in my first derivative and then take the second one and then set it to zero.

Comment: I think that's the route to go, because there's a mistake in your current $f''(x)$.

Comment: yes the way I did at first is too much of a mess.

Comment: Let me know how you're coming...

Comment: I now have the second derivative done

Comment: How does it match?

Comment: It matched I just made a mistake with the power rule. I see that 5 and -5 can not be the zeroes because it would make the function undefined because of the (25-x^2)

Comment: right you are! The first and second derivative are undefined there.

Comment: so it would have to be x=0 as the inflection point

Comment: Yes, you're correct!

Comment: Thanks for the help you explained how to solve this problem very well.

Comment: one quick question is how did you know (-75-2x^3) was x(x-5)(x+5)

Comment: It isn't: I corrected! Thanks! There is one zero: $x = 0$, as $x^2\geq 0$, hence no solution to $2x^2 + 75x = 0$

Comment: I have a quick question would this not not be -75x+2x^3 because -4(x) times (-x^2) is 4x^3

Comment: Yes Fernando. Very good observation. (See, we are all prone to stupid arithmetic errors.) I adjusted the points to check for inflection, accordingly.

Comment: @amWhy: Very good feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You have miscalculated your second derivative. First, I'd rewrite $$f'(x)=\sqrt{25-x^2}+\frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}=\frac{25-2x^2}{\sqrt{25-x^2}},$$ from which we see that $$\begin{align}f''(x) &= \cfrac{(-4x)\sqrt{25-x^2}-(25-2x^2)\frac{-x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}}{25-x^2}\\ &= \cfrac{(-4x)(25-x^2)-(25-2x^2)(-x)}{(25-x^2)\sqrt{25-x^2}}\\ &= \frac{-75x-2x^3}{(25-x^2)^\frac32}\\ &= \frac{x(x-5)(x+5)}{(25-x^2)^\frac32}.\end{align}$$ At which point(s), if any, does $f''(x)$ change signs? Such points are the inflection points. Note in particular that the denominator of $f''(x)$ is never negative--and always positive where $f''(x)$ is defined. The problem, then, amounts to finding the odd-multiplicity zeroes of the numerator of $f''(x)$ **that are in the domain** of $f''(x)$.

Comment: Using chin rule would it not be -2x/square root(25-x^2)? instead of -x

Comment: Don't forget the $\frac12$ from the power rule. That will cancel with the $2$.

Comment: yes you are right thanks!